# How to pass HTML to an included template

Tags: django, django-templates

Using Djangos template language I would like to pass HTML generated through the template language into an included template like in the following simplified example:

**field.html**

```
<input name="input_name" />
<div>{{ input_desc_html }}</div>
```

**form.html**

```
{% with input_name="test" input_desc_html=... %}
    ... should read {% for this in that %} {{ this }} {% endfor %}
    {% include 'field.html' %}
{% endwith %}
```

Obvioulsy there is something missing at `...` and I do not know how to advance from here. Is this approach even possible and if yes, how?

If not, what else would you suggest? I thought about using blocks and extending **field.html**, but it seems to me that this needs every field in its own file - or can I have local templates?

Comment: You can pass the context to `include` tag like `{% include "field.html" with input_desc_html="..." %}`.

Comment: This works for objects, strings, etc. and is what I did in the example, but the problem remains: What I want to pass is HTML that is generated by the template language. How can I get it into `input_desc_html`?

Comment: `What I want to pass is HTML that is generated by the template language` - Which HTML you are taking about? The HTML generated for field.html OR form.html OR some part of HTML in either of the HTML files... on which operation this HTML is generated?

Comment: Inside `form.html` there is an ellipsis `input_desc_html=...` annotated with `... shoud read...`. This is generated code.