# Render django form fields with additional custom markup

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

In order to follow the markup suggested by Twitter Bootstrap I want to render form fields with some additional markup besides just th `<input ... />`. Following DRY principle I created a template `bootstrap_form_field.html` containing the following:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
    {{ field.label }}
    {% if field.field.required %}*{% endif %}
</label>

<div class="col-sm-9">
    {% render_field field class='form-control' %}
    {% if field.errors %}
    <div class="help-block">
        <p class="text-danger">{{ field.errors.as_text }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="help-block">
        {{ field.help_text }}
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

To use it I put the following in my `some_form.html`:

```
{% with field=form.some_field %}
{% include 'bootstrap_form_field.html' %}
{% endwith %}
```

Now I would like to add help text to my fields that (a) contains HTML and is (b) generated through template language. In a [previous, yet unsolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962957/how-to-pass-html-to-an-included-template) of mine I asked how I can pass such HTML to the included template. Since this does not seem to work I now ask for a different approach that facilitates the following:

- The bootstrap markup should stay in one place (currently `bootstrap_form_field.html').
- The help text is specified inside a template.
- The help text may contain HTML an may be generated by template language.